# Copy data based on conditions from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first attempt at writing a macro and after spending over a week searching for solutions and trying various codes - I still can't figure this out. If there is a way to post the workbook, that would be great but I am not sure how to do this.

I need a macro to copy data from WEEK1 worksheet and paste to WEEK2 worksheet.

When the user selects WEEK2 worksheet and presses the "Update Data" button I need the Macro to

1. Go to WEEK1 worksheet
2. Un-filter the data so all data can be copied (and add the filter buttons back)
3. Copy: Starting at Column A Row 7 to Column T 
   ( Don't need to copy title / heading rows) copy down to the last row containing data unless there is a date recorded in column T then don't need to copy this row
4. Go to WEEK2 and paste the data starting at ROW 7
5. Keep all the pasted ROWS at the same height (60.00 or 80 pixels).

Here is the MACRO I have so far. It works well for steps 1 & 2 above. But it continues to copy all the rows in the worksheet even if there is no data in any of the rows.

Don't have a clue how to not copy a row based on condition of if there is a date in column T - do not copy and when I paste to worksheet WEEK2 the row height does not remain the same as the copied rows if there were more rows copied then week2 sheet had. Hope this makes sense

Here is Macro

```
Sub WEEK2UPDATE() 

' WEEK2UPDATE Macro 
' Update by Copying Data from Week 1 and Pasting to Week 2 worksheet 

 Sheets("WEEK1").Select 
 Selection.AutoFilter 
 ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0 
 Selection.AutoFilter 
 ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=24 
 Range("A100").Select 
 Selection.End(xlUp).Select 
 Range("A7:T100").Select 
 Range("A7:T100").Activate 
 Selection.Copy 
 Sheets("WEEK2").Select 
 Range("A7:T100").Select 
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _ 
 False, Transpose:=False 
 Application.CutCopyMode = False 
 Sheets("WEEK1").Select 
 ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15 
 Range("A2:T2").Select 
 Sheets("WEEK2").Select 
 Range("A2:N2").Select 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your #4 use this code to delete unneeded rows on week2 sheet and then format the row height of all pasted rows from 7 to max.  If column T is not blank for those rows you want to keep, this will need modified.

```
lrowEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' finds last row on worksheet

For iRow = lrowEnd To 7 Step -1                                     'checks rows from bottom to top
 If Cells(iRow, 20).Value <> "" Then Rows(iRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp  ' checks for a non-blank column T (20th column) to delete
 Next iRow                                                          'continue to next row

lrowEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' finds last row on worksheet after deleting
Rng = "7:" & lrowEnd                            'creates a range variable
    Rows(Rng).Select                            'selects the entire range
    Selection.RowHeight = 80                    ' set row height to 80, change this number as needed
```

Comment: This seems to resolve the issue of not copying rows that contain a date in column T.  However, since WEEK1 sheet has 50 rows and WEEK2 only starts with 20 rows, it is copying and pasting all 50 rows from WEEK1 to WEEK2 and the rows that do not contain any data do not need to be copied.  Is this happening because these rows are formatted and have drop down list in some of the columns even though there is no visible data selected or recorded in the row?

Comment: I applied the new code and it is working great.  Thank you so much

Comment: The code just copies all rows.   You could use Jbone's;  
Selection.AutoFilter 
  Range("A7:T" & ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.UsedRows.Count).Select 'select just used rows
  Selection.Copy
Although I don't trust the usedrows attribute, since it isn't update dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Should make 1-4 happen, assumes that the filter is on. Hopefully I read what you were looking for correctly.

```
  Sheets("WEEK1").Select 
  Selection.AutoFilter 
  Range("A7:T" & ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet.UsedRows.Count).Select 'select just 
  Selection.Copy                                                   'used rows
  Sheets("WEEK2").Select 
  Range("A7").Select 
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _ 
  False, Transpose:=False 
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
```